# sql query company database

Tags: mysql, sql

### database:

[image: employee table]

---

[image: works_with table]

I have a query that needs a name of employee(employee table) whose sum of total_sale(works_with table)>34000.

This means firstly group `emp_id` by `sum(total_sale)` and then `sum(total_sale)>34000` and then return their names from employee table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group by` and `having` as follows:

```
select e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
  from employee e 
  join works_with w on w.emp_id = e.emp_id
 group by e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
 having sum(w.total_sale)>34000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where (select sum(ww.total_sale)
       from works_with ww
       where ww.emp_id = e.emp_id
      ) > 34000;
```

Because this avoids the outer aggregation, this can often be faster than a method that uses `group by` explicitly.  In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `works_with(emp_id, total_sale)`.